# iteration is not appending result properly pythonsD

Tags: python-3.x

I don't understand how elements are changing in a list if we apply for loop to change that

```
w = [100,100,100,100,100,100,100]
epochs = 10
weights = []
for j in range(epochs):
    for i in range(len(w)):
        w[i] = w[i] - 5
    weights.append(w)



I am expecting to get [[95,95,95,95,95,95,95],
                       [90,90,90,90,90,90,90],
                       [85,85,85,85,85,85,85],
                       [80,80,80,80,80,80,80],
                       [75,75,75,75,75,75,75],
                       [70,70,70,70,70,70,70],
                       [65,65,65,65,65,65,65],
                       [60,60,60,60,60,60,60]
                       [55,55,55,55,55,55,55]
                   [50,50,50,50,50,50,50]][but getting this instead][1]
```

[original code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a9QK.png)

Comment: What is `t` reference in your code?

Comment: Hello, Sorry it is actually w, its just a typo there. weights.append(w)

Comment: edit your question to fix that typo pls.

Comment: I have edited the question, I have got he answer of my question as well that instead of weights.append(w) it should be weights.append([i for i in w]). but my query is what exactly is happening in the above mentioned code when i am directly appending weights.append(w) . why it is not taking the updated value of w and appending to weights ?

Answer (score 0):

**If i understand your question correctly** you want to decrease every list value by 5 every step.

```
w = [100,100,100,100,100,100,100]
epochs = 10
weights = []
for j in range(epochs):
    for i in range(len(w)):
        w[i] = w[i] - 5
    print(w)
```

The code above gives out wht you said you were expecting

Comment: Hi StanikS_PL, yeah that works but i don't wish to print those instead want to append value of w after each iteration in 'weights'.

Comment: I got the answer instead weights.append(w), it should be weights.append([i for i in w]).

Comment: But i still donot understand the logic of my original code as why i am getting that specific output.